# Flutter how to know on which part from image was tapped

Tags: flutter

I have a car image and i want to make user enable to tap on apart of it then the tapped part name will be shown. How can i do it?

[Like this image but i want to use car image not a map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hg7M.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the way I'd do this, is use a `Stack` to overlay a `GestureDetector` on your image and see what the coordinates are. You could even use a `CustomClipper` with some custom shapes, or overlay multiple `Positioned` widgets with separate listeners on it, depending on your needs.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html